# Flyway database migration tool info option not printing the version number

Tags: flyway

WE have flyway integrated with Redshift and we are using this as a simple java main program to run all our schema migrations. We also use the info command to print the current version of the database, However this command successfully runs or at least appears to run but does not print the version number. 
We have version 4.2 of the flyway jar. What is that we may be missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To manually recreate what the [info command line option](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/info) does in java code you can copy what its implementation does (from the [source](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-commandline/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/commandline/Main.java#L176)):

`MigrationInfoDumper.dumpToAsciiTable(flyway.info().all())`

An example from the docs is shown below:

```
+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version     | Description            | Installed on        | State   |
+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1           | Initial structure      |                     | Pending |
| 1.1         | Populate table         |                     | Pending |
| 1.3         | And his brother        |                     | Pending |
+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: I am running flyway's info command from my java main program and i expected the output from the metadata table but i don't see any results nor any error message.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; you're running via Java API. To see version information try emulating what the command line info command does (from the [source](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-commandline/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/commandline/Main.java#L176)):
`MigrationInfoDumper.dumpToAsciiTable(flyway.info().all())`

Comment: Thanks Harnish Carpenter. What you suggest above worked!! Thanks once again for your help on this.

Comment: @LakshmiRaju, I've updated my answer based on our comments. Please accept if it works.